# How do I connect to ADB using an Instant Client?

Tags: oracle, oracle-autonomous-db

There is common way connect to `Oracle Database on-premise` - use `instant client`. Can I use `Instant Client`?

if so, which version do I need?

Comment: You title says ADB but your question say "on-premise" - these are two different scenarios.  The general answer is yes. And use the latest version available.  For ADB read [How to connect to Oracle Autonomous Cloud Databases](https://blogs.oracle.com/opal/post/how-to-connect-to-oracle-autonomous-cloud-databases).

Answer (score -1):

yes, you can use [Instant Client](https://www.oracle.com/database/technologies/instant-client/downloads.html) 12.1.0.2 (or higher). Also, you can use ADW [Database Actions](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/sql-developer-web/sdwad/about-sdw.html#GUID-AF7601F9-7713-4ECC-8EC9-FB0296002C69) to start querying using Webclient (no need to install anything)